# Is there a SQL Server package similar to Oracle's SDO_CS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, coordinate-system, stored-procedure

I see that Oracle's [SDO_CS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_cs_ref.htm) package is able to do datum transformations.  I'd like to do datum transformations in SQL Server.

I searched, but have not found something like this for SQL Server.

*Is there a SQL Server package similar to Oracle's SDO_CS?*

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Server Spatial Tools](https://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/) is a CLR assembly that you can add to your database to assist with a number of operations that didn't come built in with the original release of SQL Server spatial objects.

It has a set of functions to do similar operations as those found in Oracles SDO_CS.  There is a [projection example](https://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SQL%20Scripts/projection_example.sql) in the source code section, though it doesn't look that helpful to me.

Comment: Thanks, I need datum transformation capability though. NADCON and NTv2 implementation would be great.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall unfortunately I haven't seen any packages that do the NTv2 or NADCON transformations.

Answer (score 1):

We are dealing with this issue right now and are looking at the DotSpatial library for .NET since it appears to have support for NADCON and NTv2.

https://github.com/DotSpatial/DotSpatial